# Yahoo Finance: Search by ISIN or Ticker without Suffix

Tags: yahoo-finance, yfinance

I have the ISIN, the Ticker symbol (without suffix, e.g. for Samsung `005930` and not `005930.KS`) and the country name. When I go to the Yahoo Finance website I am able to search with the ISIN and I get the stock I am looking for.

When I try to do it programmatically by calling the API endpoint `https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/{ TickerSymbol }?modules=financialData` it does not always work as the suffix is missing in certain cases. And I have not found a way to query with the ISIN.

So how can I find a stock using ISIN, Ticker Symbol (without suffix) respectively country name using the Yahoo Finance API?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as you've already discovered, having the suffix is necessary to retrieving data from that (and all other) endpoints.  What you could do before making the request to that endpoint is use their search endpoint to find the symbol with the appropriate suffix:

```
import requests

url = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search"
params = {'q': '005930', 'quotesCount': 1, 'newsCount': 0}

r = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = r.json()
```

And the data...

```
{'explains': [], 'count': 1, 'quotes': [{'exchange': 'KSC', 'shortname': 'SamsungElec', 'quoteType': 'EQUITY', 'symbol': '005930.KS', 'index': 'quotes', 'score': 23969.0, 'typeDisp': 'Equity', 'longname': 'Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.', 'isYahooFinance': True}], 'news': [], 'nav': [], 'lists': [], 'totalTime': 9, 'timeTakenForQuotes': 7, 'timeTakenForNews': 0, 'timeTakenForAlgowatchlist': 1, 'timeTakenForPredefinedScreener': 1, 'timeTakenForCrunchbase': 0, 'timeTakenForNav': 1}
```

Next, retrieve the symbol and then make your next request:

```
symbol = data['quotes'][0]['symbol']
url = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/{}".format(symbol)
r = requests.get(url, params={'modules': 'financialData'})
r.json()
```

```
{'quoteSummary': {'result': [{'financialData': {'maxAge': 86400, 'currentPrice': {'raw': 51900.0, 'fmt': '51,900.00'}, 'targetHighPrice': {'raw': 84000.0, 'fmt': '84,000.00'}, 'targetLowPrice': {'raw': 41000.0, 'fmt': '41,000.00'}, 'targetMeanPrice': {'raw': 54903.0, 'fmt': '54,903.00'}, 'targetMedianPrice': {'raw': 54000.0, 'fmt': '54,000.00'}, 'recommendationMean': {}, 'recommendationKey': 'none', 'numberOfAnalystOpinions': {'raw': 34, 'fmt': '34', 'longFmt': '34'}, 'totalCash': {'raw': 110830834155520, 'fmt': '110.83T', 'longFmt': '110,830,834,155,520'}, 'totalCashPerShare': {'raw': 16316.242, 'fmt': '16,316.24'}, 'ebitda': {'raw': 57610560602112, 'fmt': '57.61T', 'longFmt': '57,610,560,602,112'}, 'totalDebt': {'raw': 15665191714816, 'fmt': '15.67T', 'longFmt': '15,665,191,714,816'}, 'quickRatio': {'raw': 2.327, 'fmt': '2.33'}, 'currentRatio': {'raw': 2.883, 'fmt': '2.88'}, 'totalRevenue': {'raw': 233340506472448, 'fmt': '233.34T', 'longFmt': '233,340,506,472,448'}, 'debtToEquity': {'raw': 5.88, 'fmt': '5.88'}, 'revenuePerShare': {'raw': 34351.812, 'fmt': '34,351.81'}, 'returnOnAssets': {'raw': 0.049790002, 'fmt': '4.98%'}, 'returnOnEquity': {'raw': 0.08306, 'fmt': '8.31%'}, 'grossProfits': {'raw': 83161332000000, 'fmt': '83.16T', 'longFmt': '83,161,332,000,000'}, 'freeCashflow': {'raw': 13390567178240, 'fmt': '13.39T', 'longFmt': '13,390,567,178,240'}, 'operatingCashflow': {'raw': 51968483524608, 'fmt': '51.97T', 'longFmt': '51,968,483,524,608'}, 'earningsGrowth': {'raw': -0.159, 'fmt': '-15.90%'}, 'revenueGrowth': {'raw': 0.056, 'fmt': '5.60%'}, 'grossMargins': {'raw': 0.36016, 'fmt': '36.02%'}, 'ebitdaMargins': {'raw': 0.24689, 'fmt': '24.69%'}, 'operatingMargins': {'raw': 0.11991999, 'fmt': '11.99%'}, 'profitMargins': {'raw': 0.091230005, 'fmt': '9.12%'}, 'financialCurrency': 'KRW'}}], 'error': None}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Do you know if there is documentation on the Yahoo Finance endpoints?

Comment: How can I get the symbol with the exchange suffix like 005930.KS by providing the ISIN and Exchange Code? Also in query params, changing quotesCount to 2 do not list 2 quotes for same ISIN.